# How to manage User Related operations on client servers which are Authenticated by A Central Auth Server in Django

Tags: django, single-sign-on, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I developed a **Central Authentication Server** with [SimpleJWT](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/experimental_features.html) for a company which have multiple websites and the users of all the websites will be authenticate through the *Central Authentication Server*. Now, here is the scenario-

> The Auth Server will have the User Table with UUID, phone/email and Password which will be used for authentication. On the other hand, suppose an ecommerce site have database tables Products, transactions etc.

Now, how can I implement the user related operations like *buy, sell, transactions etc.* on the ecommerce site as I don't have any user table here.

Comment: I had the same scenario in past, I save a duplicate of data in client site too ...

Comment: But what if we need the user related operations across 10/15 sites?? And I already thought to duplicate the data but I think it's not very efficient way.

Comment: another way is that you add user id in token credential and when you need user info send a request to the authentication server.